# When to use fold and when to use foreach in list in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In my understanding, when there is need apply function for each element in list, we use fold function, right?

If just iterate the list, foreach is enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`fold`**

Use `fold` when you wish to aggregate a set into a single value. Here we say, start at zero and add each successive element to the previous one, then return the result once the set is exhausted.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(0){ (a, b) => a + b }
res10: Int = 6
```

Note that `fold` is designed for parallel computation but `foldLeft` and `foldRight` are more powerful in terms of what types they can be applied to.

**`map`**

Use `map` when you want to apply a function to each element in the set and return another set with the results.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).map(x => x + x)
res12: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

**`foreach`**

Use `foreach` when you don't want to return anything but need some side effect eg. saving each value to a DB.

```
List(1, 2, 3).foreach(x => saveToDB(x))
```

Answer (score 5):

> In my understanding, when there is need apply function for each element in list, we use fold function, right?

Nope. You use fold when you want to get a result that is a function of **all** the elements in the list. That is, you `fold` the list into one result

To apply the same function on **each** element of a list, mostly for side effects like printing to screen, you use the `foreach`, hence the name.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reduce list you are using fold

```
List(1,2,3,4).fold(0){_+_} <<-- gives you sum of elements in list
```

Foreach is used to iterate list and for example print all elements

```
List(1,2,3,4).foreach(println)
```

Comment: `foreach` is usually the wrong way, `map` is what you want in most cases.

Comment: @Reactormonk `foreach` is usually the wrong way, but I see just as many people using `foreach` for doing a manual `map` as I do people using `foreach` to do a manual `fold`

Comment: I've seen my share of using `map` to do a `foreach` too